# how to assign Strong Name to an Assembly?

Tags: .net-framework, assembly, gacutil

I have created strong name using -

```
sn -k C:\strong.snk
```

nao how to assign this key to any assembly? and where I have to use `gacutil`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling C# code you can use the `/keyfile` option to the compiler on the command line, like this:

```
csc.exe /keyfile:strong.snk /out:My.exe File.cs
```

Or if you are using Visual Studio you can set the strong name key in the project settings on the "Signing" tab check the "Sign the assembly" option and specify the key file.